# Dose Facebook allow to load dynamic meta data on jquery ajx request with html type?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a small website to share some picture if the user like, however, I used ajax to load each image within datatype if HTML.

***Issue:*** Facebook known only the meta on home pages and the metadata when I fetch front another page or URL which request by ajax is simply unknown.

Error
    URL http://camvgo.com/game/cards/4

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing    The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

This is my home pages this is the main page that contains its own metadata.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta  ..>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My images that I using ajax to query all data and return type as HTML as below format.

```
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Cam Vgo">
        <meta property="og:title" content="I know what are you thinking" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://camvgo.com/game/cards/4" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://camvgo.com/image/card/new/2017-May_31.png" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="800" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="800" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
        <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
        <meta property="og:description" content=" Facebook camvgo  Facebook camvgo  Facebook camvgo  Facebook camvgo  Facebook camvgo  Facebook camvgo  Facebook camvgo " />
        <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/camvgodotcom/" />
        <meta property="article:tag" content="quiz" />
        <meta property="article:published_time" content="2017-02-28 00:00:00" />
        <meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/camvgodotcom/" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="102782740235682" />
      </head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Ajax.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
..........,
Success:function(data,status){
     $(data).appendTO("#result");
}})
 });
```

Comment: You can not set Open Graph meta data via JavaScript; it must be contained in the HTML code the server returns when the shared/liked URL is requested.

Comment: OK thank, So I understand much now